# Html5 draggable emoticons inside text

Tags: html

I'm looking for some pointers for how to have a draggable emoticon (smiley) inside of an editable HTML5 text editor. The catch is that the user can't delete the emoticon. The text can be edited all around the emoticon, and the emoticon can be dragged to different places, but we can't allow it to be deleted.

Anybody have a starting point I can use to come up with this edit control?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://script.aculo.us/
If you include this API you can easily create draggable DIVs or images.

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty cool. I wish they had a few more demos however. Nonetheless, cool find.

Comment: At the demo section are some different draggable divs: http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/draggable/ But if you have any questions ask, but post the code here somewhere.